# PocketSphinx compiling for android on Windows

Tags: android, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I have to build and run the PocketSphinx sample for android

My system for android development in Windows 7 + Eclipse

I have installed NDK and Cygwin
My Cygwin does not have gcc or g++ with it right now.
Do you I need these compilers in cygwin ?

I have already put these modules
- bison
- make
- automake
- libiconv
- libtool
- python interpreter

on it.

I am confused whether I need to perform following steps for sphinxbase and pocketsphinx ? as suggested http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/comment-page-2/#comments

./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install

and if I so would I need gcc or g++ on cygwin ?

Please advise,

thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with this tutorial too on windows, but now I get it work and wrote a little tutorial, maybe it will help:

https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo

Answer (score 0):

You do not need NDK anymore, you can compile just the raw source. For more information see the official CMUSphinx tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: Thanks,I understand I defintiely need swig to create java wrappers arround native code for the available sample of pocketsphinx android proj. However I was able to build the project without having gcc or g++ on cygwin, I beleive NDK itself has it own cross compiler to compile for android architecture and it does not need gcc or g++ as a cygwin module to compile in this particular case..

Comment: That's true, NDK has it's own gcc. You don't need to install another one. If your question is about that.

Answer (score -2):

I use gcc, have worked on several NDK projects using this.

Comment: SO are you saying gcc on cygwin will compile native code for android ?? Is that not the job of NDK's compiler ??

Comment: No... i am not saying that i am saying its best compiler for c

Comment: Thanks but that does not answer my question, it rather confused me